# Submitting additional info after the account is signed up an logged in RAILS 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what I'm trying to do is when the account is created and logged in, it redirects to a page that gives the choice between being a student or a trainer, after the choice made,it redirects to `new`*`informationclientspath` or `new information`*`trainer_path` , after that the account needs to fill the information required such an avatar, the location, etc... when I submit it displays every info correctly. the problem is that the account can be a student and a trainer as the same time because when i'm on show and click on new information client, I can create another info which I don't want to, so the system is 1 account = 1 info (Client or Trainer).

I honestly think that my method is wrong, so i ask you if you have another method to suggest.